# How to calculate time since last event on a temporal serie?

Tags: python, pandas

Working with Python 3.5 and Pandas 0.19.2

I describe my problem: I have in a data frame different "IDActivo" sorted by date and time ascending. Well, I have a field called Result whose values are NaN or 1. I need to calculate for each row how long ago was the last N time where the result field was 1 for that particular "IdActivo".

This is my dataframe:

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'IdActivo': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'Fecha': ['1990-01-02','1990-01-03','1990-01-04','1990-01-05','1990-01-08',\
                                  '1990-01-09','1990-01-10','1990-01-11','1990-01-12' ,'1990-01-15',\
                                  '1990-01-16', '1990-01-17', '1990-01-18','1990-01-19','1990-01-22',\
                                  '1990-01-23 ', '1990-01-24', '1990-01-25','1990-01-26','1990-01-29'],
                   'Hora': ['10:10:00','10:11:00','10:12:00','10:13:00','10:10:00',\
                                  '10:10:00','10:17:00','10:14:00','11:14:00','12:14:00',\
                                  '10:10:00', '10:20:00', '14:22:00','15:22:00','16:22:00',\
                                  '10:10:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00','00:00:00','00:00:00']})
def Inicio():
    numHoraDia = '10:10:00'
    numDia = 2  # para nosotros el 2 será el martes ya que le añadimos +1 al lunes que es 0 por defecto
    nomDiasSemanaHora = "  Resultado";    inpfield = "Fecha" ;    oupfield = "Dia_Semana"

    df_final = Fecha_Dia_Hora(df,inpfield,oupfield,numHoraDia,numDia,nomDiasSemanaHora)
    print (df_final)


def Fecha_Dia_Hora(df, inpfield, oupfield,numHoraDia,numDia,nomDiasSemanaHora):
    ord_df = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    ord_df[inpfield] = pd.to_datetime(ord_df[inpfield])
    ord_df[oupfield] = ord_df[inpfield].dt.dayofweek + 1
    ord_df[nomDiasSemanaHora] = np.NaN
    ord_df.ix[np.logical_and(ord_df[oupfield] == numDia, ord_df.Hora == numHoraDia), [nomDiasSemanaHora]] = '1'
    return ord_df.sort_index()

def Fin():
    print("FIN")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Inicio()
    Fin()
```

I show you an example derivated of the dataframe you can see on the code:

[imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnLPE.png)

What functions must I investigate to get it?

Thanks

Angel

Comment: dig into cumsum

Comment: I dont understand good why I need this function. I need to substrack two differents dates: Date of every row - Date of the last n time Result was 1 for its idactivo. What does relation exist between this and "cumsum??

Comment: If you provide toy example of the *resulting* data you expect (i.e. illustrating the contents of the result column you're talking about and what dataframe output you expect), I can show you. Without it, it's painful and it will remain a comment.

Comment: I have added to my answer a example derivated from the dataframe included on my code. Please say me if you need some aclaration more or more details. Thanks